# Unable to install pyOpenSSL

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, windows-10, pyopenssl

I dual booted a Windows 10 partition on a Macbook Pro:
Mac: El Capitan (64-bit)
Windows: Windows 10 64-bit, formatted with the fat file system

On Windows, I installed cygwin and Python 2.7. Through cygwin, I installed pip and gcc.

I also tried installing cffi with http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#cffi, but when I ran pip install `cffi-1.8.2-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl`, I got the error: `cffi....whl is not supported on this platform`. Then I tried many things I can't remember, I think I even tried downloading a tar file, and then now, when I run pip install cffi, I'm told it's already installed.

I then ran `pip install pyOpenSSL`,however, I got this error:

```
 gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -ggdb -O2 -pipe -Wimplicit-function-declaration -fdebug-prefix-map=/usr/src/ports/python/python-2.7.10-1.x86_64/build=/usr/src/debug/python-2.7.10-1 -fdebug-prefix-map=/usr/src/ports/python/python-2.7.10-1.x86_64/src/Python-2.7.10=/usr/src/debug/python-2.7.10-1 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c build/temp.cygwin-2.6.0-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.c -o build/temp.cygwin-2.6.0-x86_64-2.7/build/temp.cygwin-2.6.0-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.o
    build/temp.cygwin-2.6.0-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.c:433:30: fatal error: openssl/opensslv.h: No such file or directory
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-9Emw8c/cryptography/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-wy64bj-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-9Emw8c/cryptography/
```

I also got this error when I did `pip install cryptography`.

I read somewhere that I should try: `pip install --global-option build_ext --global-option --compiler=mingw64 pyopenssl`, and I got:

```
Skipping bdist_wheel for pyopenssl, due to binaries being disabled for it.
Skipping bdist_wheel for cryptography, due to binaries being disabled for it.
Installing collected packages: cryptography, pyopenssl
  Running setup.py install for cryptography ... error
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-fIb1xc/cryptography/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" build_ext --compiler=mingw64 install --record /tmp/pip-7flSlN-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running build_ext
    generating cffi module 'build/temp.cygwin-2.6.0-x86_64-2.7/_padding.c'
    creating build
    creating build/temp.cygwin-2.6.0-x86_64-2.7
    generating cffi module 'build/temp.cygwin-2.6.0-x86_64-2.7/_constant_time.c'
    generating cffi module 'build/temp.cygwin-2.6.0-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.c'
    error: don't know how to compile C/C++ code on platform 'posix' with 'mingw64' compiler

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-fIb1xc/cryptography/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" build_ext --compiler=mingw64 install --record /tmp/pip-7flSlN-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-fIb1xc/cryptography/
```

Can someone please advise what's wrong??

Update: After installing `mingw64x86_64-openssl: OpenSSL encryption library for Win64 toolchain` through cygwin, and running `pip install pyopenssl`, I got:

```
 running build_ext
    generating cffi module 'build/temp.cygwin-2.6.0-x86_64-2.7/_padding.c'
    creating build/temp.cygwin-2.6.0-x86_64-2.7
    generating cffi module 'build/temp.cygwin-2.6.0-x86_64-2.7/_constant_time.c'
    generating cffi module 'build/temp.cygwin-2.6.0-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.c'
    building '_openssl' extension
    creating build/temp.cygwin-2.6.0-x86_64-2.7/build
    creating build/temp.cygwin-2.6.0-x86_64-2.7/build/temp.cygwin-2.6.0-x86_64-2.7
    /usr/bin/clang -fno-strict-aliasing -ggdb -O2 -pipe -Wimplicit-function-declaration -fdebug-prefix-map=/usr/src/ports/python/python-2.7.10-1.x86_64/build=/usr/src/debug/python-2.7.10-1 -fdebug-prefix-map=/usr/src/ports/python/python-2.7.10-1.x86_64/src/Python-2.7.10=/usr/src/debug/python-2.7.10-1 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c build/temp.cygwin-2.6.0-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.c -o build/temp.cygwin-2.6.0-x86_64-2.7/build/temp.cygwin-2.6.0-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.o
    build/temp.cygwin-2.6.0-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.c:433:10: fatal error: 'openssl/opensslv.h' file not found
    #include <openssl/opensslv.h>
             ^
    1 error generated.
    error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-ZsWN3h/cryptography/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-D2XH0P-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-ZsWN3h/cryptography/
```

Comment: Do you have _OpenSSL_ installed (as _pyOpenSSL_ is just a _Python_ wrapper around it)?

Comment: yes I have. It's in \cydrive\c\OpenSSL-win64. I installed from source: https://www.openssl.org/source/

Comment: That path seems like you have installed _OpenSSL_ for _Win_, most likey you have to install (or build if unavailable) the _Cygwin_ version. As a quick test run `/cydrive/c/OpenSSL-win64/bin/openssl version -a` and see what (if) it outputs.

Comment: It outputs: `OpenSSL 1.1.0 25 Aug 2016, built on: reproducible build, date unspecified, platform: , compiler: cl " "VC-WIN64A, OPENSSLDIR: "C:\Program Files\Common Files\SSL", ENGINESDIR: "C:\Program File\OpenSSL\lib\engines-1_1"`

Comment: Hmm, well, some tools that need _OpenSSL_ just run it (and from its output figure out its path) or just get it from _${PATH}_, and I doubt that _/cydrive/c/OpenSSL-win64/bin_ is in there. Could you create a symlink: `/usr/bin/openssl` to point to the executable, and try installing the module again? Or is there some way to pass the _OpenSSL_ installation dir to _pip_?

Comment: hmm, there is an executable: `/user/bin/openssl.exe`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123551/discussion-between-cristifati-and-user3918985).

Comment: Fixed by directly installing python-openssl bindings from cygwin. Closing issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and installed the libssl header files so I could compile the python module:

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```